# How to use did you mean and showing results for suggestions from google

Tags: python, google-search, google-search-api

So basically I would like to use a spell checker for different places, countries, types of foods in my program google search engine does a pretty good job in identifying mistakes in the sentences. Am trying to get the suggestion as a text i have no earthly idea how to do this but here is what I did and it doesn't work.

```
from googlesearch import search 
ip="What would you like to search for? "
for url in search(ip, stop=1):
     print(url)
```

This gives me the url I am not looking for the url am looking a list with suggestion what it could be.

Comment: Maybe this will help? [how to implement python spell checker using google's "did you mean?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8428767)

Answer (score 1):

To use a spell checker for different places, countries, and types of foods in your python program, you can use the **pyenchant** library. This library provides a wrapper for the **Enchant** spell checking library, which supports multiple languages and dictionaries.

### Explanation

The **pyenchant** library allows you to create a **SpellChecker** object that can check the spelling of words and suggest corrections. You can also add or remove words from the dictionary, or use a custom dictionary file.

To use the **pyenchant** library, you need to install it using the command:

```py
pip install pyenchant
```

Then, you can import it in your python program and create a **SpellChecker** object with the desired language code. For example, to create a spell checker for English, you can use:

```py
import enchant
speller = enchant.SpellChecker("en_US")
```

To check the spelling of a word, you can use the **check** method, which returns True if the word is correct, or False if it is not. For example:

```py
speller.check("pizza") # True
speller.check("piza") # False
```

To get a list of suggested corrections for a misspelled word, you can use the **suggest** method, which returns a list of strings. For example:

```py
speller.suggest("piza") # ['pizza', 'pita', 'pia', 'pica', 'pisa']
```

To add a word to the dictionary, you can use the **add** method, which takes a string as an argument. For example:

```py
speller.add("sushi") # adds sushi to the dictionary
speller.check("sushi") # True
```

To remove a word from the dictionary, you can use the **remove** method, which also takes a string as an argument. For example:

```py
speller.remove("sushi") # removes sushi from the dictionary
speller.check("sushi") # False
```

To use a custom dictionary file, you can use the **enchant.DictWithPWL** class, which takes a language code and a file name as arguments. The file should contain one word per line. For example, if you have a file called **mydict.txt** with the following content:

```
Paris
London
Tokyo
New York
pizza
sushi
pasta
```

You can create a custom spell checker using:

```py
import enchant
speller = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US", "mydict.txt")
```

This spell checker will use the words from the file as well as the default English dictionary.

### Examples

Here are some examples of using the **pyenchant** library to check the spelling of different places, countries, and types of foods in your python program.

- Check the spelling of a sentence and print the misspelled words and their suggestions:

```py
import enchant
speller = enchant.SpellChecker("en_US")
sentence = "I love to travel to diferent places and try new cuisines."
words = sentence.split()
for word in words:
  if not speller.check(word):
    print(f"{word} is misspelled. Suggestions: {speller.suggest(word)}")
```

Output:

```
diferent is misspelled. Suggestions: ['different', 'deferent', 'deterrent', 'decent', 'deficient']
cuisines is misspelled. Suggestions: ['cuisine', 'cuisines', 'cousins', 'quinces', 'quinsies']
```

- Add some words to the dictionary and check the spelling of a sentence:

```py
import enchant
speller = enchant.SpellChecker("en_US")
speller.add("Mumbai")
speller.add("kimchi")
sentence = "I visited Mumbai last year and enjoyed the kimchi there."
words = sentence.split()
for word in words:
  if not speller.check(word):
    print(f"{word} is misspelled. Suggestions: {speller.suggest(word)}")
```

Output:

```
No output, since all words are correct.
```

- Use a custom dictionary file and check the spelling of a sentence:

```py
import enchant
speller = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US", "mydict.txt")
sentence = "My favorite cities are Paris, London, and Tokyo."
words = sentence.split()
for word in words:
  if not speller.check(word):
    print(f"{word} is misspelled. Suggestions: {speller.suggest(word)}")
```

Output:

```
No output, since all words are in the custom dictionary file.
```